# Reording data frame rows in r

Tags: r, dataframe, rows

I want to reorder the rows in my dataframe so that they are not "grouped," There was no grouping function performed. My data frame is quite large so I want a function that could do this for me instead of manually reordering the rows.

My dataframe right now looks like:

```
id     start time
1         11:30 am
1         11:30 am
1         11:30 am
2         12:30 pm
2         12:30 pm
2         12:30 pm
3         1:30 pm
3         1:30 pm
3         1:30 pm
```

I would like it to look like

```
id     start time
1         11:30 am
2         12:30 pm
3         1:30 pm
1         11:30 am
2         12:30 pm
3         1:30 pm
1         11:30 am
2         12:30 pm
3         1:30 pm
```

Comment: Just to be clear, are you (1) cycling `id` itself, and `start time` is just along for the ride; or (2) cycling the _combinations_ of `id` _and_ `start time`.

Comment: I would like a solution for both situations, but cycling id independent of start time is the more immediate need I have.

Comment: Let me know if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68185678) works for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

With `dplyr` (and optionally `chron`), along with a dataset `df` like the one in your example

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~id, ~`start time`,
  1,   "11:30 am",
  1,   "11:30 am",
  1,   "11:30 am",
  2,   "12:30 pm",
  2,   "12:30 pm",
  2,   "12:30 pm",
  3,   "1:30 pm",
  3,   "1:30 pm",
  3,   "1:30 pm"
)
```

here's a solution for **arbitrary groupings** (for cycling) **of your choice**. Per your [request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68185303/reording-data-frame-rows-in-r#comment120509574_68185303), we cycle here by `id` alone, but we can just as easily cycle by the *combination* of any variables (ex. both `id` and `start time`).

Optionally, we can also treat `start time` as `times` of day rather than as text, sortable chronologically (where `"12:30 PM"` comes *before* `"1:30 PM"`) rather than alphabetically (where `"12:30 PM"` comes *after* `"1:30 PM"`).

```
library(dplyr)
library(chron)


# ...
# Code to generate your dataset 'df'.
# ...


new_df <- df %>%
  # OPTIONALLY convert time strings into "times" objects, sortable chronologically.
  mutate(`start time` = chron(times = format(strptime(`start time`, format = "%I:%M %p"), "%H:%M:%S"))) %>%
  # Group HOWEVER YOU DESIRE, here by 'id' alone.
  group_by(id) %>%
  # Index each row by the order in which it occurs within its group.
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% ungroup() %>%
  # Sort by that order, and then discard the index column.
  arrange(rn) %>% select(!rn)


# Print result.
new_df
```

Given the `df` from your example, our results for `new_df` will look like:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 2
     id `start time`
  <dbl> <times>     
1     1 11:30:00    
2     2 12:30:00    
3     3 13:30:00    
4     1 11:30:00    
5     2 12:30:00    
6     3 13:30:00    
7     1 11:30:00    
8     2 12:30:00    
9     3 13:30:00
```

### Tip

If you wish to cycle by the *combination* of (say) `id` and `start time`, simply use `` group_by(id, `start time`) `` instead of `group_by(id)`. Further sorting can be done within the [`arrange()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/arrange.html) step.

### Aesthetics

If you want, you can convert the `start time` column from `times` objects back into text, in your original format or in any other format of your choice (via format codes specified in [`strptime()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/strptime)).

```
new_df <- new_df %>%
  mutate(`start time` = trimws(format(as.chron(`start time`), "%l:%M %P")))


# Print result.
new_df
```

This will yield the output:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 2
     id `start time`
  <dbl> <chr>       
1     1 11:30 am    
2     2 12:30 pm    
3     3 1:30 pm     
4     1 11:30 am    
5     2 12:30 pm    
6     3 1:30 pm     
7     1 11:30 am    
8     2 12:30 pm    
9     3 1:30 pm
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the previous answer:

You can create an index. If you want to arrange just the id then just group by the ID. This will give you a variable that you can arrange to your hearts content. I would recommend arranging your times before you do this step though.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tribble(
  ~id, ~start_time,
  1, '11:30 am',
  1, '11:30 am',
  1, '11:30 am',
  2, '12:30 pm',
  2, '12:30 pm',
  2, '12:30 pm',
  3, '1:30 pm',
  3, '1:30 pm',
  3, '1:30 pm'
)

df <- df %>%
  group_by(id) %>% # id is the variable we want to rearrange
  mutate(id_idx = row_number()) %>% # create an index for the position of each id in the data
  arrange(id_idx,id) %>% # arrange it so that the first 1 is first, then the first 2, then the first 3
  select(-id_idx) # remove the extra index column

# A tibble: 9 x 2
# Groups:   id [3]
     id start_time
  <dbl> <chr>     
1     1 11:30 am  
2     2 12:30 pm  
3     3 1:30 pm   
4     1 11:30 am  
5     2 12:30 pm  
6     3 1:30 pm   
7     1 11:30 am  
8     2 12:30 pm  
9     3 1:30 pm
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `seq_along` per *id* using `ave` and use the result in `order`.

```
x[order(ave(x$id, x$id, FUN=seq_along)),]
#  id start time
#1  1 11:30   am
#4  2 12:30   pm
#7  3  1:30   pm
#2  1 11:30   am
#5  2 12:30   pm
#8  3  1:30   pm
#3  1 11:30   am
#6  2 12:30   pm
#9  3  1:30   pm
```

Data:

```
x <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="id     start time
1         11:30 am
1         11:30 am
1         11:30 am
2         12:30 pm
2         12:30 pm
2         12:30 pm
3         1:30 pm
3         1:30 pm
3         1:30 pm")
```

Comment: I think the author might want an extensible way to cycle through arbitrary combinations of variables (see [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68185303/reording-data-frame-rows-in-r#comment120509574_68185303)) in the future, not just `id` for now.

Comment: I think this could be done by adding another grouping variable to `ave`.